# Dataframe filter the highest value from each day and save it again in a DataFrame with 2 columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

i got a DataFrame like this. **df:**

[image]

I apply the following function to df

```
df_new = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="longtime",freq="D")).agg({df.columns[1]: [np.max]})
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data= df_new)
print(df_new)
```

following you see the **output of df_new**. the DatFrame has 1 column. but i want the "longtime" and "amax" to be stored in 2 separate columns. how do I have to adjust the function of df_new to achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `[]` from one element list in `agg` for avoid `MultiIndex` and add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df_new = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="longtime",freq="D"))
            .agg({df.columns[1]: np.max})
            .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the function as is and just drop the first level of the header rows and then reset the index:

```
df_new = df_new.droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()
```